Adding Empty Pages After Chapter Titles and After Chapters But Only inside Main Matter
I wanted to add more buffers after chapter titles and after chapters themselves, in \mainmatter only. From what I've gathered, LaTeX by default adds a page if the chapter ends in an odd page, but I wanted to add two more pages after that, not mattering if it's odd or even. And I also wanted to separate the chapter title into its own page.
Currently, what I've been doing looks something like this:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\emptypage{
  \newpage 
  \ 
  \newpage
}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter

  \chapter{Preface}
    \lipsum[2-7]

  \mainmatter

  \part{Life}
    \chapter{Life 1}
      \emptypage
      \lipsum[2-4]
      \emptypage
      \emptypage
      \emptypage
    \chapter{Life 2}
\end{document}

I'm also experimenting with:
\newcommand\clearedpage{
  \clearpage
  \begingroup
    \null
    \clearpage
  \endgroup
}

which does work, but I wasn't able to take out fancyhdr's header, and the numbering to make it blank-looking.
That's kinda too manual though, and tedious, and error prone. So I wondering if I could add a macro or some document configuration somewhere. What would be a good solution here?
Also, is there a way to omit page numbers on these buffer pages (including the chapter and part pages)? (I'm currently using the fancyhdr package in my project.)

why not just use \part and redefine \partname?

I don't understand. Would that solve the before and after buffer pages for example?

But I meant to keep the starting of the parts and chapters on odd pages, keeping the logic of adding an empty page if the chapter ends in an odd page. I'm just adding 2 extra empty pages after that.

oh, sorry. misread it earlier. have deleted comment.

there's a package you can use which I'm blanking on, but then you have e.g. \cleartooddpage[] etc. you could build on that definition and include a \pagestyle in the optional argument. then incorporate that into a wrapper around \part or \chapter or redefine or whatever.

I've added an improvement.
